# LARAVEL AUTHENTIFICATION using two tabels

Tags: laravel

I wan too make authentication using Laravel with users and roles tables where users had id as primary key username password and role_*id as foreign key and roles table had role_*id as primary key and name and after verifying the username and password i wan to get the value of name from role table into the controller to make add condition [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuPhW.jpg)
the question is how can i get the value of the name column ?
I tried to make relationship between tables[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRPm.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRPm.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCQDs.png picture of code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRPm.png)  picture of Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWFxe.png)picture of  code here
`enter code here`

Comment: Can you add more context and code in your question ?

Comment: *"I want to [...]"* and *"I tried to [...]"* are not questions... What is the specific issue you're trying to solve? What, specifically, is not working? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76772898/edit) and include more details.

Comment: pleaze a i need a help

Comment: Slightly better, but please do not include your code as **images**... Code is **text**; please, once again, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76772898/edit) and include your code as text. Also, if you're getting an error with `$user = Auth::user();`, then `$user->role->name`, it simply means that `$user` is `null`, and `null->role->name` is not valid. You need to make sure you're logged in for that code to work.

Comment: how can i set to$user=Auth::user() a value

Comment: See Tim Lewis's response. You should add the code under consideration to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for more on this. You will increase the probability of others responding to your question if you invest the time to follow the stackoverflow guidelines.